# Building after Android Studio 2.0 alpha5 upgrade gives FildNotFoundException for play-services8.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

After upgrading Android Studio 2.0 to preview 6, after all the sync, clean, rebuild, I am now getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/EPICEIRIE 2/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/8.1.0/jars/classes.jar (No such file or directory)
```

I tried updating the SDK tools all to their most recent version, and even tried updating the play-services to 8.4.0, but no luck...

Does anyone else run into similar problem? Have you found a solution for it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with Update your Gradle plugin to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'
```

Comment: wow that was stupid of me! I had it set at alpha5 for some reason... Thanks for pointing it out! - will accept answer in 5 min when I am allowed to do so!